# images not rendering in production

Tags: node.js

I have deployed my node.js express app to production via a docker file, however, the images are not being rendered, and browser standard placeholder images are being rendered in-place of these.

In order for my app to render these images, is there something I am doing wrong? Is there a piece of code I need to include?

My file structure is as follows

- base directory > public > icons
- base directory > index.js

Relevant portion of my `index.js` server file

```
 const { join } = require("path");
    app.set('views', join(__dirname, 'views'));
    app.use(express.static(join(__dirname, 'public')));
    
    
    const port = 3000
    
    var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
    app.use(cookieParser())
    
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
    app.use(cookieParser());
    
    process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    
    
    
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    
    app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
      res.render('index',{
          data: 'name'
      })
    })
```

Here is the error message I get when I try to open the image file

[image]

ejs file:

```
<% data.countries.forEach(function(count){ %>
 

       
    <div class="flex">
      <div class="template">
              <div class=“Country>
                  <img class="img" src="/icons/<%= count.icon %> " width="25" height="25"  />  <%= count.name %> 
                </div>
      
              <div class ="Category">
    
                <%= count.categories.map(cat=>cat.name).join(' | ') %>
              </div>
              
       </div>
    </div>
      
      
      
    
        <% }); %>
```

Comment: Hello, could you show us your `index.ejs` file please, thank you

Comment: @FelixFong added to the question

Answer (score 0):

Can you open the file directly by his path?

Comment: Added to the question

Comment: You can just leave comments here instead of editing your answer.... But opening the icon link points to the error... not sure what you mean

Answer (score 0):

One possible answer is because inside your EJS file, your image is pointing at a URL that looks something like `/icons/HK.png`, but your ExpressJS public path is set to `/public` indeated here:

`app.use(express.static(join(__dirname, 'public')));`

So one possible solutions is to add a new public path for your icons set by adding this code:

```
app.use('/icons', express.static(join(__dirname, '/public/icons')))
```

Comment: Don't I want to give the server access to all of the public folder however?

Comment: And sorry, but where are you getting `images` from?

Comment: 1) Sorry for the `/public/images` thing, it was my mistake, I updated my code.

2) You are not full access to the entire public directory, you are only giving the public access to the icons directory if traffic is coming from the `/icons` route

Comment: But my CSS is also in my public directory, so thus I lose that when pushing live